# How to list chapters of a textbook PDF file in qpdfview?

Tags: 18.04

I need [qpdfview](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/qpdfview.1.html) to list the chapters on a PDF textbook file which has bookmarks in it, as Acrobat in Windows does with that same file. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

I tried every option on the qpdfview menu bar but didn't find anything, google also don't have an answer.

How do I get qpdfview to show the chapters as Adobe Acrobat does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check

**View -> Docks -> Outlines**

It will display Chapters panel on the left side of qpdfview app.

**View -> Docks -> Bookmarks** will display Bookmarks panel there